# Convert int to timespan in SQL script (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, json, type-conversion

The query is done in an sql script. 
My Problem : 
I need to pass the data in a model as json.
Thats why i need to convert it to a timespan in the sql script.

```
--TEMP
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
SET @startDate = '01-09-2016'

DECLARE @endDate DATETIME
SET @endDate = '03-10-2017'
--END


SELECT
Firstname,
Lastname,
COUNT(Token.Id) as Tokens,
**CONVERT(time, SUM(DATEDIFF(ss, Token.ArrivalTime, Token.CompletionTime)), 57) as [Time]**
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Token ON Token.Employee_Id = Employee.Id
WHERE AssignmentTime >= @startDate and AssignmentTime <= @endDate
and Status = 2
GROUP BY Firstname, Lastname
ORDER BY Tokens DESC
FOR JSON PATH
```

The error is:

```
The explicit conversion from data type int to time is not allowed
```

What the output should look like : "Hans", "Muster", 5, 400

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output in formatted text (not images)

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?  (looks like T-SQL / SQL Server)

Comment: Its SQL Server. Sorry for that, im not that used to sql.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is with SUM function. because you are trying to do summation to a time. You need to use DATEADD function.
Think like this if try summation between 13:50 and 21:45 it wont work

Answer (score 1):

At the end it wasn't that hard. I didnt parse the int to timespan in the sql query. I got a error in every variation, no matter what I tried.
Thats my solution:

```
DATEDIFF(ss, Token.ArrivalTime, Token.CompletionTime) as TimeInSeconds
```

In the ViewModel which is getting passed in the controller, I parse it:

```
    public int TimeInSeconds { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time
    {
        get { return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeInSeconds); }
    }
```